# Can we upload/download files from kubernetes pod using c#?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi, iformfile

I have one API deployed in kubernetes Pod. We have common persistent volume claim storage and want to upload text or any format file in this location using c# code. A .net core api will perform these operation. I am using IFormFile for file input.

Can we do read/write operations with these pods using c# ?

Comment: You can attach persistent storage like a local directory and so you can use the normal file IO function from C# to read and write. I'd suggest you try to write your file and if you struggle with a concrete problem, post a new question with some more details and code.

Comment: Are you trying to write to persistent data from inside your application code, or bypass the API layer to write directly to the volume from outside the cluster?

Comment: Yes David, i am trying to write to persistent volume claim. My API Pod will perform this operation.